# How to send variables between different views on XCODE?

Tags: variables, uiviewcontroller, multiple-views

I am currently trying to create an application that will allow the user to build a "fake" report card. How would I be able to use variables to go from SecondViewController to ThirdViewController? I would need to be able to take Users' text from 15 textField to a new view where it can be saved as a picture, so they can share it with friends on facebook or email.